# Copying File Fails in when open in fmOpenReadWriteMode

Tags: delphi

i am working on a little byte patching program but i encountered an error.

copying the file before modifying fails with no error, (no copied output is seen) but the file patches successfully.

Here is the Patch Code

```
procedure DoMyPatch();
var

  i: integer;
  FileName: string;
  input: TFileStream;

  FileByteArray, ExtractedByteArray: array of Byte;

begin
  FileName := 'Cute1.res';

  try
    input := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenReadWrite);
  except
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error Opening file');
      Exit;
    end
  end;

  input.Position := 0;
  SetLength(FileByteArray, input.size);
  input.Read(FileByteArray[0], Length(FileByteArray));

  for i := 0 to Length(FileByteArray) do
  begin
    SetLength(ExtractedByteArray, Length(OriginalByte));
    ExtractedByteArray := Copy(FileByteArray, i, Length(OriginalByte));

// function that compares my array of bytes
    if CompareByteArrays(ExtractedByteArray, OriginalByte) = True then
    begin
      // Begin Patching

     CopyFile(PChar(FileName), PChar(ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.BAK')),
            true);  =======>>> fails at this point, no copied output is seen.

        input.Seek(i, SoFromBeginning);


          input.Write(BytetoWrite[0], Length(BytetoWrite)); =====>>> patches successfully

          input.Free;
      ShowMessage('Patch Success');
      Exit;
    end;

  end;
  if Assigned(input) then
  begin
    input.Free;
  end;

  ShowMessage('Patch Failed');


end;
```

sidenote : it copies fine if i close the filestream before attempting copy.

by the way, i have tested it on Delphi 7 and XE7.
  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot copy the file because you locked it exclusively when you opened it for the file stream, which is why `CopyFile` fails.

You should close the file before attempting to call `CopyFile`. Which would require you to reopen the file to patch it. Or perhaps open the file with a different sharing mode.

Some other comments:

- The exception handling is badly implemented. Don't catch exceptions here. Let them float up to the high level.
- Lifetime management is fluffed. You can easily leak as it stands. You need to learn about `try/finally`.
- You overrun buffers. Valid indices for a dynamic array are `0` to `Length(arr)-1` inclusive. Or use `low()` and `high()`.
- You don't check the value returned by `CopyFile`. Wrap it with a call to `Win32Check`.
- The `Copy` function returns a new array. So you make a spurious call to `SetLength`. To copy the entire array use the one parameter overload of `Copy`.
- Showing messages in this function is probably a mistake. Better to let the caller provide user feedback.

There are loads of other oddities in the code and I've run out of energy to point them all out. I think I got the main ones.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Could you explain more or an example on these two especially the second one.

The exception handling is badly implemented.
Lifetime management is fluffed. You can easily leak as it stands.

Comment: You shouldn't catch any exceptions. Let somebody higher up the call stack do that. Protect objects with try/finally. That has been well covered here. One of my highest voted answers has a comprehensive coverage.

Comment: One of these other oddities is `if Assigned( input ) then input.Free;`. This is a double check for assigned, because that is the main work of `TObject.Free`: if assigned call the destructor